# hash template metafunction and function

Tags: c++, c++11

Any computation is possible at compile-time with C++ template metafunctions. Therefore, I was considering, if the following were possible:

```
void my_function(char const* string_ptr)
{
  switch (hash_function(string_ptr))
  {
    case hash_metafunction<"yoohooo">::value:
      ...
      break;

    case hash_metafunction<"woooooo">::value:
      ...
      break;

    ...
  }
}
```

Can you give leads as to where to find code (library) for both the hash function and template metafunction. If none such library exists, can you give hints on how I might roll the template metafunction myself? I am particularly worried about the `char const*` parameter to the template metafunction. Maybe some preprocessor magic is possible?

Comment: String literals can't be template parameters. However, user-defined literals may be what you need: `"yoohooo"_hash`.

Comment: This is why I am asking for preprocessor magic, i.e. with variadic templates 'y', 'o', 'o', 'h' ... might be possible.

Comment: Actually, you *can't* use templaty UDLs for string literals... But if you wrote `foo<'y', 'o', 'o', ...>` it could of course be done.

Comment: Yes, yes, I'd like to know if it is possible to transform the "yoohoo" string with a preprocessor macro into 'y', 'o', 'o', ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a `constexpr` function? Of course implementing that hash could be a pain. You'll have something like this:

```
// maybe another return type
constexpr uint64_t hash_metafunction(const char* input) {
    // replace some_value with the hash implementation
    return some_value;
}

void my_function(char const* string_ptr)
{
  switch (hash_function(string_ptr))
  {
    case hash_metafunction("yoohooo"):
      ...
      break;

    case hash_metafunction("woooooo"):
      ...
      break;

    ...
  }
}
```

The `hash_metafunction` function would be executed on compile-time.

*Edit*: This is a naive implementation, which basically converts the input string to a `uint64_t`:

```
constexpr uint64_t do_the_hash(const char* input, uint64_t value_so_far) {
    return *input ? do_the_hash(input + 1, (value_so_far << 8) | *input) : value_so_far;
}

constexpr uint64_t hash_metafunction(const char* input) {
    return do_the_hash(input, 0);
}
```

Live demo [here](http://ideone.com/GcJMG).

*Edit*: I've implemented a compile time *MD5*, you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/mfontanini/Programs-Scripts/blob/master/constexpr_hashes/md5.h). In order to use it, do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "md5.h"

int main() {
    constexpr auto value = ConstexprHashes::md5("constexpr rulz");

    std::cout << std::hex;
    for(auto v : value) {
        if(((size_t)v & 0xff) < 0x10)
            std::cout << '0';
        std::cout << ((size_t)v & 0xff);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

This prints out the hash: "b8b4e2be16d2b11a5902b80f9c0fe6d6".

Comment: There you go, edited my answer. Everything is done recursively.

Comment: Amazing, too bad a library with similar functionality does not exist.

Comment: The thing is, implementing something like a SHA1 using constexpr would be *really* painfull, since you require recursion everywhere.

Comment: It only needs to be done once, then everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: I've implemented an MD5 constexpr hash. See my answer for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a `constexpr` version of `MurmurHash3` as a [gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/mattyclarkson/5318077).

```
int main() {
  constexpr uint32_t hash = Murmur3_32("some_string_to_hash", 0xAED123FD);
  assert(hash == 4291478129);
}
```